# How can I remove paginated SEO titles from my WordPress site?

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to change the text of the SEO title on a paginated page on WordPress? Or remove it entirely?

Right now, it's like "Blog | Page 2" I want to translate it to my own language or remove it.

PS: WordPress language is already in my own language, but it still displays in English. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem with this code:

```
    <title>

        <?php

            global $page, $paged;

            wp_title('|', true, 'right');

            bloginfo('name');

            $site_description = get_bloginfo('description', 'display');

            if ($site_description && (is_home() || is_front_page()))

                echo " | $site_description";

            if ($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2)

                echo ' | ' . sprintf(__('Sayfa %s', 'twentyten'), max($paged, $page));

        ?>

    </title>
```